# Problem implementing Partial Least Squares Regression

Tags: r, regression, least-squares, pls

I’m trying to implement the Partial Least Squares Regression model in R using the `pls` package. The following data frame represents my data, where I have two response variables and three explanatory variables.

```
library(pls)
df <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(20),
                 x2 = rnorm(20),
                 x3 = rnorm(20),
                 y1 = rnorm(20),
                 y2 = rnorm(20))
model <- plsr(c(y1, y2) ~ x1+x2+x3, ncomp = 3, scale = TRUE, data = df)
```

However, when I run the model, I always get an error message.

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = c(y1, y2) ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data
> = df) :    variable lengths differ (found for 'x1')

I believe that the data frame is not correctly structured. Would anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: ``c(y1, y2)`` is longer than ``x``. The vectors on either side of ``~`` should all be the same length. I'm not familiar with plsr, but you perhaps want to ``cbind(y1, y2)`` to join them as 2 column vectors, rather than concatenate them into a single vector